# SQL server Table partition with history data

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 db with 110 mill rows.To improve the performance of canned report, I am suggesting to partition the table. However the user query fetches inception to date data in all their runs.

Which means partition with date/month will not be helpful if there is no specific date range for data select.

Can you please suggest how I can implement the partition to gain performance.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think partition is the only solution?

Comment: Hi Felix, No. It is one of the solution. As part of performance gain exercise, I have to ask to work on partition feasibility.